# Instead of if statements use a loop?

Tags: c#

Is there any way I could use a loop instead of writing out all of these if/else statements? I'm not sure if it is possible and I have looked online and haven't seen very many guides that would help me.

```
int numberOne = random.Next(id2) + 1;
int numberTwo = random.Next(id2) + 1;
int numberThree = random.Next(id2) + 1;
int numberFour = random.Next(id2) + 1;
int numberFive = random.Next(id2) + 1;

        if (id1 == 1)
        {
            int total = numberOne;
            string newmessage = "message";
            return Json(newmessage);
        }
        else if(id1 == 2)
        {
            int total = numberOne + numberTwo;
            string newmessage = "message";
            return Json(newmessage);
        }
        else if (id1 == 3)
        {
            int total = numberOne + numberTwo + numberThree;
            string newmessage = "message";
            return Json(newmessage);
        }
        else if (id1 == 4)
        {
            int total = numberOne + numberTwo + numberThree + numberFour;
            string newmessage = "message";
            return Json(newmessage);
        }
        else if (id1 == 5)
        {
            int total = numberOne + numberTwo + numberThree + numberFive;
            string newmessage = "message";
            return Json(newmessage);
        }
```

Comment: No need for `if` or (explicit) `loop`. Instead use `var total = Enumerable.Range(1, id1).Sum(z => random.Next(id2) + 1);`.

Comment: BTW, my above comment assumes that `int total = numberOne + numberTwo + numberThree + numberFive;` is a typo and should include `numberFour`.

Comment: @mjwills it was a typo. I apologize.

Comment: It doesn't hold in this case (@mjwills extreme code reduction does here), but typically, if you have `if (a==X1) {} else if (a==X2) {} etc`, using a `switch` statement is often a good solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you likely want to do is:

```
int total = Enumerable.Range(1, id1).Sum(z => random.Next(id2) + 1);
string newmessage = "message";
return Json(newmessage);
```

There is no need for an explicit loop (since `Enumerable.Range` will do the looping for you).

Comment: This was a good way to do it! Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Since you probably need a loop and not using lambdas, you can go with something like this:

```
   int total = 0;
   for (int i = 0; i < id1; i++) 
   {
      total += random.Next(id2) + 1;
   }
   return Json("message"); // I assume you want to return total here;
```

The reason this works is that if id1 is 1, you'd break out of the loop after doing 1 random.Next.  If id2 is 2, then you'd run thru the first number and then add the 2nd number automatically.  With this approach, you could support any number, not just up to 5.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with @mjwills solution, but here's an explanation of how you might do it in a step by step fashion:

The first thing I did was declare `random`, `id1` and `id2`.  I varied `id1` during testing.  When you post code, you should include this kind of thing, that way the folks help you don't have to reverse engineer what you are thinking:

```
var id1 = 5;
var id2 = 10;
var random = new Random();
```

Then, I realize that in each case, you have a chunk of the same code (the last two lines), so I extracted that duplicated code out and put it at the bottom of the *loop* (and I used NewtonSoft's JsonConvert class to convert things to JSON (which I'm assuming your `Json` function does) - I have that NuGetted into my test project):

```
string newMessage = "message";
return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(newMessage);
```

Finally, here's the loop you were asking about.  I initialize total (I could put that initialization in the `for` loop, but it's clearer this way).  Also note that the `for` loop is non-standard, it loops from 1 to N inclusive (generally `for` loops are 0 to N-1).  This loop is between the initialization code and the final code:

```
var total = 0;
for (var i = 1; i <= id1; ++i)
{
    total += (random.Next(id2) + 1);
}
```

What @mjwills code does is convert that into a single expression.  The `Enumerable.Range(1, id1)` part generates a collection of consecutive integers starting at `1` and having `id1` entries.  Then he calls `.Sum`, passing it a *lambda* that represents a function to run on each item in the collection before it is summed.  My loop basically does the same thing.

Altogether, it looks like this:

```
var id1 = 5;
var id2 = 10;
var random = new Random();

var total = 0;
for (var i = 1; i <= id1; ++i)
{
    total += (random.Next(id2) + 1);
}

string newMessage = "message";
return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(newMessage);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this, it also allows you init 5 numbers using any algoritm, not just the same

```
    //var random=new Random();
    //var id2=2;
    //var id1=4;

    var data = new int[]{
    random.Next(id2) + 1,
    random.Next(id2) + 1,
     random.Next(id2) + 1,
     random.Next(id2) + 1,
     random.Next(id2) + 1
   };

var total=0;
for ( var i = 0; i < id1; i++)
{
     total+=data[i];
}
    var newmessage = $"message#{id1.ToString()}, total {total.ToString()} ";
    
    return Json(newmessage);
```